# Does .NET have an equivalent for Python's issubset method?

Tags: .net, python, set

**UPDATE:**

As @Blender pointed out in Python `set('aab').issubset(set('abb')) == True`.  For my situation this needs to return false.  The number of each character needs to be taken into account.

---

Basically I have two strings and I would like to determine if one is a subset of another.  Example:

```
String A: abcd
String B: dbace
String A is a subset of string B
```

Characters can be in any order and there can be repeating numbers of characters.  I had tried ordering the strings and then using String.StartsWith, but this does not work in certain situations.  Example:

```
String A: abcdd
string B: abbcdd
Ordering these and using StartsWith returns false because string B has two "b"s
```

I did some looking around and found Python's issubset method which appears to do what I want, so I'm curious if anyone has come across its equivalent in .NET (or an effective method someone has come up with on their own).

NOTE: I am looking for subsets, not anagrams.

Comment: Try converting the strings into sets (i.e. no duplicate entries). Iterate over one and check which elements are contained within the other set. If the elements contained within the other set constitute the original set, you've got a subset.

Comment: What do you mean by "no duplicate entries"?  Just to be clear,  `aab` should not be a subset of `abb`.

Comment: `set('aab').issubset(set('abb')) == True` in Python. `set('aab') == set('ab')` as well.

Comment: Gah! Sorry, I didn't know that.  Updating my question.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Would my solution be able to solve your problem or I was wrong? I can't understand the Jeff comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing built-in that I know of that behaves as you want it.  Strictly speaking, this isn't a real subset as it should be doing set comparisons as it is in Python (where every item in a set is unique) but it should be simple to cook one up.

```
public static bool IsSubsetOf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> lhs, IEnumerable<TSource> rhs)
{
    // O(m+n)
    var contents = rhs.ToList();
    foreach (var item in lhs)
    {
        if (!contents.Remove(item))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
"aab".IsSubsetOf("abb");      // false
"foo".IsSubsetOf("food");     // true
"foo".IsSubsetOf("goof");     // true
"bar".IsSubsetOf("barf");     // true
"abcd".IsSubsetOf("dbace");   // true
"abcdd".IsSubsetOf("abbcdd"); // true
```

If you want true set mechanics, it is just as simple.

```
public static bool IsTrueSubsetOf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> lhs, IEnumerable<TSource> rhs)
{
    return new HashSet<TSource>(lhs).IsSubsetOf(rhs);
}
```

Comment: I just tried your second method and I don't think it passes the `aab` - `abb` test (it is returning true).  Do you get the same results or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's actually expected.  The first method does what you wanted.  But it isn't a _true_ [subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) (where duplicates are not present in either set).  It would be correct for your definition of subset here.  The second method does not do what you wanted _but_ is shown if you wanted to know if it was a real ("true") subset.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution is to sort both of them and check the subset by `Contains` method.

```
new String(A.OrderBy(o=> o)).Contains(new String(B.OrderBy(o=>o)))
```

**UPDATE:**

```
new String(A.OrderBy(o=> o)
            .Distinct())
     .Contains(new String(B.OrderBy(o=>o)
                           .Distinct()))
```

Comment: @JeffMercado But still I think that It works correctly. If you don't want to remove duplicates then you can just add the `Distinct` function call to method chain.

Comment: But that's not what was asked for now is it?  But even still, duplicates or not, your solution still wouldn't work...

Comment: @Jani, I downvoted.  Sorry for not leaving a comment.  The reason I downvoted was because if you read the paragraph above my second code block you will see that I have tried a method that is pretty much identical to this (I used `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`) and already said it does not work.  If you run your code against the example in my second code block you will see this method does not work.

Comment: @AbeMiessler But If you add the Distinct method to method chain it will satisfy your requirement AFAIU.